# How come I can't open my .html with Live Server in VS Code when I haven't opened a parent directory of it as a workspace folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

I installed Live Server in VS Code for the first time and am trying to open an .html file with Live Server. I'm following the simple instructions provided here [on the official installation page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), but to no avail.

I right-click my file in the Explorer as instructed, but "Open With Live Server" doesn't show. I've even tried right-clicking the tab and that doesn't work either. I've quit and re-started VSCode and that didn't work. I set Chrome as my default browser in settings.json and that didn't work. I double checked to make sure Live Server is installed and enabled globally and it is. Please help me figure out what's going on! Thank you!

[image: Right clicking my file under Open Editor]
[image: Right clicking the file tab]
[image: Live Server is indeed installed]

Comment: Did you try re-installing the extension and then running VS Code again?

Comment: Yup I tried that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I figured it out. I had to open my file by selecting "Open Folder" and then open my folder from there. Then I was able to select my file under the Explorer tab and right-click to open with Live Server. I'm not sure why it worked that way. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's happened to me few times. My problem was the folder and files names.
Check those names and don't use spaces or weird characters.